# Is it appropriate to change the scope of a question with a bounty on it?

Tags: support

What is the difference between clarifying and broaden the scope of a question?

A hint in an answer (which also solves partly the problem) lead me to new insight of the problem, but if I would edit the question, it would broaden the scope, I guess. Should I just try it? I'm asking because there's already a bounty on [that question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70444/how-to-create-a-custom-date-formatter-for-grouping-in-views).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule is not changing the meaning of a question when it has already answers. That is true even when there aren't bounties offered for the question. Since you say, "A hint in an answer […] lead me to new insight of the problem" I take it as you would write something similar to the following:

> I did as [user who answered] suggested, but now I have another problem.

If that is the case, I would not edit the question to add that.

Clarifying is done when you see all the users answer about B, but you asked about A. Even in that case, I would rather avoid editing the question, move over, and ask a new question being sure it is not seen as duplicate of the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to give advice without actually seeing the changes in context. The following assumes we're talking about a question of your own, and not someone else's...

A good rule of thumb is to look at the current answers to the question. If your edits would leave the current answers making no sense, then you shouldn't make them.

If your edits mean that the current answers would still answer the original question, and that original question is still part of the new question body, I don't see any harm at all in expanding it.

But while doing that, just make sure that you're not broadening the question beyond the scope allowed by the FAQ. It might well be that you need a new question that refers back to the bountied one, it really depends.

Comment: I updated the question found here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70444/how-to-create-a-custom-date-formatter-for-grouping-in-views